# Metrics to use for multiclass classification

Tags: multiclass-classification

I was asked in an interview that I have imbalanced dataset of multiclass categories. For example out of 1000 data points 700 fall in cat1 , 75 in cat2, 90 in cat3 , 50 in cat4, 50 in cat6 , 35 in cat7.

### **How should I approach the problem?**

My answer :

- approach1: after data processing  creating binary model keep cat1 as 1 and rest cat0
- approach2: Make models on cat1 , cat2 , cat3 leaving rest. Find important features using ensemble , bagging , boosting techniques

### **What would be the evaluation metrics ? and why to choose so ?**

My answer:

- confusion matrix , F1 score , weighted average(cost to
  False Positive , False negative) , logloss

### **You get 5 models , model1 is performing good for 1 category , Model2 is performing good on 2 categories and so on. How would you decide which model to use ? why ?Explain with measurable number**

My answer :

- model which is explainable , computationally less expensive , robust to outliers , minimum feature space , whose weighted scores are good.

Clearly, my interviewer was super disappointed. But I am still looking for the answer. Please help. Thanks in advance